# How to create an Eventcallback which has the arguments in blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I need to create a Eventcallback for this following method

```
public async Task methodA(bool isLoading)
{
    IsLoading = isLoading;
    this.StateHasChanged();
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I've tried it using following

```
EventCallback callback=> EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, methodA);
```

but I am getting a error called

> can't convert method group to EventCallback

I need to create this event callback and pass it to the child components using cascading parameters as following

```
<CascadingValue Value=callback>
    @Body
</CascadingValue> 

   @code{
      EventCallback callback=> EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, methodA);

      public async Task methodA(bool isLoading)
     {
       IsLoading = isLoading;
       this.StateHasChanged();
       await Task.CompletedTask;
     }
   }
```

so what is wrong with above code ??and how to create an eventcallback for above method?

Comment: Your method takes an input parameter of type `bool` --> `EventCallback<bool> callback => EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, (bool isLoading) => methodA(isLoading));`

Comment: @AstridE. you should turn your comment into an answer so I can upvote it. Solved my issue!

Comment: @JesseQ Done. I appreciate your feedback, and am glad that my comment was helpful!

Comment: Why are you using an EventCallback and calling StateHasChanged - the whole point of an EventCallback is that it automatically does that for you - also, why are you declaring this method as an async Task, then not doing anything async except awaiting a completed Task?

Answer (score 3):

Your method takes an input parameter of type `bool`, which means that the `callback` object needs to be an `EventCallback<bool>`:

```
EventCallback<bool> callback =>
    EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, (bool isLoading) => methodA(isLoading));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I was working with a DynamicComponent and needed to send an EventCallback as one of the parameters to handle an event.  Thanks!